# onSubmit of Iframe in Parent Window is possible?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, iframe

Is it possible to call an `onsubmit` function of an iframe in the parent window? I need this because I want to check when the iframe is submitting and pass some value of the iframe textbox to a textbox in parent window.

Heres my jQuery in the parent window and `ExpDate` is the textbox in the iframe.

```
var expDate = $("#ExpirationDate").text();
$('#frmAdd').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (expDate != null && expDate != "") {;
        $('#ExpDate', window.parent.document).val(expDate);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code should work fine, although I would guess that you need to set `expDate` *inside* the submit handler, otherwise you're only setting the value on page load possibly before a value is set.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sir will it work if the onsubmit is located in the Parent window?

Comment: No, you need to place the Javascript in the page within the iframe

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so its not possible that i include and onsubmit function of my iframe in my Parent window?

Answer (score 2):

I made a demo on codepen because SO snippets are sandboxed:

http://codepen.io/VincentCharpentier/pen/KVWyeK

the important part :

```
// From the parent frame :
// 1. get the iframe with id "myFrame"
// 2. get the element with id "myForm" in this iframe (your form)
// 3. add an event handler
window.frames["myFrame"].contentWindow.document
      .getElementById("myForm")
      .onsubmit = function() { 
          alert("Submit !");
          // return false if you want to avoid redirection
          // return false;
      }
```

Once you have the `document` object of the iframe you are free to do anything you would do with the main `document` object.

So you can replace `.getElementById("myForm")` with `.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]` if you need.

---

### Edit

As you asked how to access other elements in the iframe, here it is :

In your top frame, you can keep a reference of the window element of the iframe :

```
// keep a reference to the window element of the iframe :
var winIFrame = window.frames["myFrame"].contentWindow;
```

with this you can access any DOM element in the iframe :

```
winIframe.document.getElementByID("SomeID")
winIframe.document.getElementsByTAgName("SomeTagName")
// ...
```

so for the textarea you have two options :

1 - If the textarea is inside the form :

```
// add the event onsubmit handler
winIFrame.document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function() { 
    // "this" refers to the form element
    // querySelector takes CSS selector as argument (like jQuery)
    // return the first element that match
    alert(this.querySelector("#ExpirationDate").value);
    return false;
}
```

2 - If you need to interact with stuff outside the form, use the `winIFrame.document` :

```
// add the event onsubmit handler
winIFrame.document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function() { 
    // "this" refers to the form element
    // querySelector takes CSS selector as argument (like jQuery)
    // return the first element that match
    alert(winIframe.document.getElementById("ExpirationDate").value);
    return false;
}
```

**Note** : I updated the codepen snippet

Comment: Sir I really appreciate it! just want to ask additional question on how can i get the value of the textbox inside the `myForm` iframe?

Comment: I'm not sure how to access it with jquery, but I will put a pure JS solution in the edit part of my answer